# Add incremental tick marks on the Y-axis in barplot() for R

Tags: r, bar-chart, histogram, intervals

I created a relative frequency histogram, but am trying to add minor tick marks on the y-axis. When I use the     `axis()` function as in the following code:

````
```displacement_hist <- barplot(table(dissertation$displaced)/nrow(dissertation),
    axis(2, at=seq(0, 5, .25)),
    main = "Global Displacement", #Give your chart a title
    xlab = "Displacement by Numbers", #Label the x axis
    las = 2,
    cex.lab=.75,
    cex.axis =.75,
    cex.names = .75,
    ylab = "Relative Frequency")```
````

it produces this image: [My histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxBGi.png). When I use the same code with `ylim` as follows:

````
```displacement_hist <- barplot(table(dissertation$displaced)/nrow(dissertation),
    axis(2, at=seq(0, 5, .25)),
    ylim = c(0, .05),
    main = "Global Displacement", #Give your chart a title
    xlab = "Displacement by Numbers", #Label the x axis
    las = 2,
    cex.lab=.75,
    cex.axis =.75,
    cex.names = .75,
    ylab = "Relative Frequency")```
````

It produces this image: [My histogram2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a2nK.png). I would like the values for the tick marks on the y-axis to range from 0 to .05 with intervals of .0025. How can I do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You did not indicate where you got the `minor.tick` function. If it is the one in the `Hmisc` package you should include loading the package in your sample code. If you read the manual page, `?minor.tick`, it clearly states that setting `nx=1` or `ny=1` results in no tick marks being drawn. See `?par` and the arguments `xaxp=` and `yaxp=` for setting the major tick marks. Provide data if you want an illustration.

Comment: Also noticed. You cannot run a function inside the `barplot` function. The `axis()` function and the `minor.tick()` functions are separate commands that come after the `barplot()` function.

Comment: So what would you recommend trying?

Comment: Also, I don't know why I included `minor.tick()` in the question as it's not in the code I ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to get what you want. First we have to create some fake data that is similar to yours:

```
set.seed(42)
diss <- data.frame(displaced=sample(50, 200, replace=TRUE))
displacement_hist <- barplot(table(diss$displaced)/nrow(diss), ylim=c(0, .05), 
    main = "Global Displacement", xlab = "Displacement by Numbers", 
    las = 2, cex.lab=.75, cex.axis =.75, cex.names = .75, ylab = "Relative Frequency")
axis(2, seq(0, .05, by=.0025), labels=FALSE, tck=-.01)
```

[image: Bar Plot]

Comment: I see, I needed to add the ``axis()`` function after the ``barplot()`` function Thank you!